# Ideas/theories on grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I am looking for some help/ideas on how to structure (table wise) infinitely nest groups in SQL.

```
EX.
group1 will contain  a,b,c
group2 will contain  d,e,f
group3 will contain  h,i,j
group4 will contain  k.l.m

groupA will contain group1,group2
groupB will contain group3

groupA1 will contain groupA,groupB,group4
```

each lowest level group will refer to a list of scans in a different table (in this example lets say group1 group2 group3 and group4 are the lowest level)

this should be able to support an infinite number of groups

I know this is vague but i am trying to find out how to structure and manage something like this...

I am trying for both tables and queries. So far I have this:

```
Scan Table
((uniqueID),barcode,user,date,group)
Groups Table
(groupID,groupName,groupRef)
```

but i am having trouble "Creating" GroupA

in terms of queries i would need to know what are the lower level groups and get a list of all items in a group.

Comment: Can you please elaborate using a table and values, or an example, I am not sure what you are looking for when you say infinite number of groups... are you saying you want to create a table like this??? are you trying to design a query???

Comment: I think you're going to need some sort of parent/child structure.  Based on your little example, your table might have 3 columns: `ID`, `NAME`,`PARENT_ID`.  Your top level objects wouldn't have a null in the parent column, your lowest level would never be used as a parent.

Comment: Nested sets is another way of doing this type of thing. You can google "sql nested sets" and you will find tons of example of how to do this. This is an excellent approach that is super performant. If you use the adjacency module you will end up needing recursive ctes to retrieve your data. If you have a lot of data this can get really slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example it looks like a parent-child structure would do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #ParentChild (Parent VARCHAR(30), Child VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO #ParentChild
VALUES
('group1','a'),
('group1','b'),
('group1','c'),
('group2','d'),
('group2','e'),
('group2','f'),
('group3','h'),
('group3','i'),
('group3','j'),
('group4','k'),
('group4','l'),
('group4','m'),
('groupA','group1'),
('groupA','group2'),
('groupB','group3'),
('groupA1','groupA'),
('groupA1','groupB'),
('groupA1','group4')
```

This will allow you to store an (almost) infinite number of groups. The "limit" depends on the SQL Server version (e.g. SQL Server 2008R2: File size (data): 16 terabytes) which should be good enough ;-)

As for your specific questions:

```
--"what are the lower level groups?"
--"i.e., give me all the groups, except those that contain another group
SELECT Parent
FROM #ParentChild
EXCEPT
SELECT t1.Parent
FROM #ParentChild t1
INNER JOIN #ParentChild t2
  ON t1.Child = t2.Parent

--"get a list of all items in a group"
SELECT Child
FROM #ParentChild
WHERE Parent = @Group
```

Another option would be to store the data using the hierarchyid [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) data type

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about Hierarchical Data. Sql Server has built-in support for this. You should read through this article:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

That article discusses using the new [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) type, as well as Parent/Child alternative.

Comment: Can you identify all objects at the bottom of a chain using this, if it's a ragged hierarchy like the OP is discussing?